# Planning to photograph Paris Opera Garnier, Eiffel and Montmerte

Tags: street-photography, safety, insurance

I live in Turkey and I'm planning to visit Paris next week. I'm amazed how gorgeous Opera Garnier is. Is it allowed to photograph inside that building? And is tripod allowed?

Also I've read that Montmarte is not really safe. I want to go there at dusk so it means it'll be dark when I'm done there. Some people say there are thieves or creepy people around. I don't want my all equipment stolen.

Same question goes for Eiffel too. I'm planning to shoot there at dawn 4-5 am in the morning.

So I'd appreciate any help from Parisians or travelers who have been there. Thanks.

Comment: Not quite an answer to your question, so I am adding it here, but where tripods are not permitted, I have often used one of two alternatives: either a bean/rice bag and just set the camera on it, or a manfrotto arm (196B-2) and a super clamp - which can be attached to a railing, door, wheelchair, etc. As for safety the best bet is good insurance :-)

Comment: Posting as a comment since it is only a partial answer, but the Eiffel tower seems to be in a pretty decent part of town from what I could gather when I was there.  I wasn't there at 4 in the morning, but I was there fairly late taking photos and it seemed fine.  (This was about 3 years ago.)  I'd also recommend visiting the Louvre.  They allow photography and it has some wonderful architecture in addition to the great collections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a Parisian, I can tell you that you can shoot inside the Opéra Garnier. However, you may have to buy a guided tour to be allowed to shoot. I don't think tripod is allowed but you sure can use a monopod or any other device which is not too big.

Montmartre, as most touristic places, knows its pickpockets, thieves, riff-raff... Close your bags and hold them tight, and do the same wherever you go in Paris (métro —subway—, buses, etc.). The Eiffel Tower is crowded with men who will try to force you to buy their crap at very expensive prices.
Make sure not to be surrounded by little groups of children : while one asks you the time or a direction, the others will pick into your pockets and rob you.

Besides that, if you're not alone, you got nothing to fear, late or early. Keep your gear hidden as long as possible, not to tempt thieves.

Hope I didn't afraid you, enjoy your stay. Parisian shop/bar owners and taxis are sometimes rude but street people are welcoming. As AJ said, I recommend the Musée du Louvre and le Jardin des Tuileries which leads to the Louvre. Make sure to visit the Musée d'Orsay which is gorgeous too.

Comment: Louvre was already in my plan. I'll check le Jardin des Tuileries and Musée d'Orsay too. Thanks for the detailed info. I'll buy a monopod also:) I'm going with my wife, does that count alone:)